# How to see saved data of Google cloud SQL without creating a table?

Tags: google-app-maker

I am working on an app maker project. I have used Google Cloud SQL as a database. Now my question is How can I see what data has been saved previously by going to the database directly.

Currently I have to create a table to see the saved data. But I don't want to use the table to see those data. Is there any way to see those data??

Comment: I think it's possible if you have access to your SQL console, but I have never messed around with that. The only other way would be to use your export data functionality from within App Maker. Doing this you can choose to export an entire deployment including all relation tables or just a single table.

Comment: You can use something like SQL workbench.

Answer (score 1):

I am using metabase for fast data prewievs, but you can as well install phpmyadmin or mysql workbench.